# How to add data to DB using a POST request in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I tried to add a record to the database using a POST request in Node JS. I tried with the following,

```
<form action="/addDevice?deviceToken=" onsubmit="location.href = this.action + this.token.value; return false;" method="POST">
    <input name="token" type="text" value="3456as7dssa65d56da78s9d9sd67"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Device" class="btn btn-success"/><br>
</form>
```

in Node JS, I did,

```
app.post('/addDevice', function (req, res) {

   device.addNewDevice(req.data.deviceToken, function (err, result) {
      if (err) return res.json(err);
      var msg = 'Added ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows.';
      console.log('bode : ' + req.data.deviceToken);

      // display all devices
      device.getDevices(function (err, devices) {
         if (err) return res.json(err);
         res.render('device_view.html', {devices: devices, msg: msg});
      });

   });
});
```

When I'm running this I got the following error,

`Cannot GET /addDevice?deviceToken=3456as7dssa65d56da78s9d9sd67`

How can I fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `<form action="/addDevice?deviceToken=" onsubmit="location.href = this.action + this.token.value; return false;" method="POST">`
Is there any other way to define it as POST ??

Comment: GET action take place in onsubmit i think, whta is the purpose for that?

Comment: I want to pass the value of input, to the action like `addDevice?deviceToken=3456as7dssa65d56da78s9d9sd67`

Comment: you want to get `value` after form action in server, right?

Comment: Why do you hardcode 'value' in text field?it will show a text field with that `value` na?

Comment: Yes. i want to pass it.. I just put a default for testing purpose.. :)

Comment: then no need of onsubmit, just use `method="post" action="/addDevice"` only, you will get data from POST request.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js